# How to list remote windows host shared directories in Python?

Tags: python, windows

Is there any possibility to obtain list of shared directories of given remote windows host from python?
I have machine in my HOMEGROUP, let's say: COMP and have there shared directories "Users".
In Python I can list files using

```
os.listdir(r"\\COMP\Users")
```

but I'd like to know what folders are shared, e.g. Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`NetShareEnum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387) to list all of the `STYPE_DISKTREE` shares, including hidden shares such as "ADMIN$" and "C$".

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

netapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('netapi32')

STYPE_DISKTREE  = 0x00000000
STYPE_PRINTQ    = 0x00000001
STYPE_DEVICE    = 0x00000002
STYPE_IPC       = 0x00000003
STYPE_MASK      = 0x000000FF
STYPE_TEMPORARY = 0x40000000
STYPE_SPECIAL   = 0x80000000

MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = 0xFFFFFFFF
ERROR_MORE_DATA = 0x00EA

class NET_API_BUFFER(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

class SHARE_INFO(NET_API_BUFFER):
    pass

class SHARE_INFO_1(SHARE_INFO):
    _fields_ = (('shi1_netname', wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('shi1_type',    wintypes.DWORD),
                ('shi1_remark',  wintypes.LPWSTR))

LPNET_API_BUFFER = ctypes.POINTER(NET_API_BUFFER)

class LPSHARE_INFO(LPNET_API_BUFFER):
    _type_ = SHARE_INFO

class LPSHARE_INFO_1(LPSHARE_INFO):
    _type_ = SHARE_INFO_1

LPLPSHARE_INFO = ctypes.POINTER(LPSHARE_INFO)

if not hasattr(wintypes, 'LPBYTE'): # 2.x
    wintypes.LPBYTE = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)

if not hasattr(wintypes, 'LPDWORD'): # 2.x
    wintypes.LPDWORD = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD)

netapi32.NetShareEnum.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPWSTR,  # _In_    servername
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_    level
    LPLPSHARE_INFO,   # _Out_   bufptr
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_    prefmaxlen
    wintypes.LPDWORD, # _Out_   entriesread
    wintypes.LPDWORD, # _Out_   totalentries
    wintypes.LPDWORD) # _Inout_ resume_handle

netapi32.NetApiBufferFree.argtypes = (
  LPNET_API_BUFFER,) # _In_ Buffer

def list_shares(server_name):
    pshare_info = LPSHARE_INFO_1()
    entries_read = wintypes.DWORD()
    total_entries = wintypes.DWORD()
    resume_handle = wintypes.DWORD()
    shares = []
    while True:
        result = netapi32.NetShareEnum(server_name,
                                       1,
                                       ctypes.byref(pshare_info),
                                       MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                                       ctypes.byref(entries_read),
                                       ctypes.byref(total_entries),
                                       ctypes.byref(resume_handle))
        if result and result != ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            raise ctypes.WinError(result)
        try:
            for i in range(entries_read.value):
                info = pshare_info[i]
                if info.shi1_type & STYPE_MASK == STYPE_DISKTREE:
                    shares.append(info.shi1_netname)
        finally:
            free_result = netapi32.NetApiBufferFree(pshare_info)
            if free_result:
                raise ctypes.WinError(free_result)
        if result != ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            break
    return shares
```

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        server_name = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        server_name = '127.0.0.1'
    print('\n'.join(sorted(list_shares(server_name))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [PySMB](https://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb). With the method [listShares](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html).